# Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: n attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cis.Ite.Mixed, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=365143bb27e7ac8b' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

I get this exception when I run the project .exe which has reference to few binaries (not directly this one). I am on .Net 4.5 and have verified I using 64 bit. Could you please advise cause and fix for this issue? I have tried other forums also. Thanks much.

Comment: You might want to show some code and be a bit more specific about what and where exactly in your code it is failing.  Have you placed breakpoints in the code and walked into the exception so that you know where it's at, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually a bitness problem and probably due to a referenced dll, if you are compiling into a 64bit application, then simply switch it to 32bit.

The simplest solution is to set the `Platform Target` to be `x86` on the project properties